# Closing out my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

No want for account
Seek to leave Stack Overflow
How does one close then?

Comment: this probably belong on meta

Comment: WHaaaaaaaaaaaaaay?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account

Comment: yours or someone else's?

Comment: +1 for haiku-compliance.

Answer (score 8):

I think deleting an account should be an option... When a user deletes his account all his answers and comments should become "posted by anonymous user". After all privacy is the right, and IMHO SO should honor it.

Comment: When you voluntarily use a service, you voluntarily forfeit your 'right' to privacy to use said service. Rights are something that no one can take away from you, but you can choose not to exercise them.  If you were forced into using Stack Overflow, then yes, you would have a 'right' to privacy.  However this is a private exchange.

Comment: Remember there's also the data dump. You can't delete that, so there's no way to really protect someones privacy, as you suggest.

Comment: they should instead belong to "Community", and become cw

Answer (score 4):

You have to email the team and ask them:

> team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know about outright deleting the account, blanking out your profile data will come pretty close.

That said, questions about Stack Overflow itself should be directed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  Sorry to see you go!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just stop using it? It's not as if there's a cost associated.