# How come the Tagged list only shows 3 of the 4 tags for this question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31048/how-to-close-account-on-stackoverflow-com).

The "ide" tag doesn't show up in the Tagged list.

Edit:

It might just be me, I'm running Windows Vista, FF 3.5.5

Update: Seems to be working now. I'm not sure why. Maybe because Ólafur Waage added the ide tag to this question?

Comment: I realize this is a really minor bug, just asking out of curiosity. Sorry if this is a known issue, I couldn't find any reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the question was migrated, and one of the tags doesn't exist on the target site.

This gets fixed by the daily vote sync script.